# rewrite utf8 characters in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8

I am trying to rewrite é to e, using the htaccess file.
All the following rules have all failed.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)é(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xa9(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%C3%A9(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]
```

I have the following debug output, however am unable to figure out what it says.

> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/'
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/'
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (1) pass through /translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation -> /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/ -> translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/'
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation -> /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/ -> translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/'
>
> 197.178.121.8 - - [24/Feb/2014:00:29:35 --0800] [www.speaksheets.com/sid#7ff60b7a0318][rid#7ff60d1edf58/initial] (2) [perdir /home/speaksheets.com/public_html/] rewrite 'translation/how-to-say-bon-app\xc3\xa9tit-in-french-bon-appetit/' -> '/index.php'

The question is, what is wrong with this rule, `RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xa9(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xa9(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]
```

Is fine and should work (worked in my testing also).

But from rewrite log it appears some rule in internally rewriting it to `index.php` first.

Just make sure this above rule is **very first rule** in your .htaccess.

Comment: you are right, i have written it as the first rule and now its working perfectly

Comment: Can you please provide full ```.htaccess``` with removing ```index.php``` form url?

Comment: Comment section is for discussing question or posted answer, not for asking new code. You should post a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters. All non-ASCII characters must be escaped to percent escapes like `%C3%A9`. `^(.*)é(.*)` should never match a valid URL. `\xYY` is not defined as a byte escape sequence in Apache as far as I'm aware, so `^(.*)\xc3\xa9(.*)` does not mean what you think it means either. The only valid rule is `^(.*)%C3%A9(.*)`, which contains the URL escaped version of a UTF-8 representation of "é".

Comment: "é" is represented as \xc3\xa in the debugging log, does it have any implications on the matching of the rules?

Comment: I'm not sure if `\xYY` has any special significance, but it certainly does not stand for a byte escape sequence in either Apache or URLs as far as I'm aware, so it certainly shouldn't have the effect you may think it has.